# Coding a web browser on Windows using a layout engine?

Tags: windows, web, web-browser

I've never attempted anything like this before but what I want to do is code a browser for Windows.

I know that I can use the web-browser control that Microsoft has released, but I'm interested in seeing how the problem is solved from a lower level. So I want to know what layout engine I should be looking at? Or is a layout engine the best way to go?

I've been looking at WebKit, but it seems rather Mac-centric, so I'm wondering if there are any more practical one's for windows?

Has Microsoft released the source code for their [webbrowser winforms control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) in the .Net framework? That would be dependent on the CLR anyway, I suppose?

Any suggestions?

Comment: How low do you want to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin by studying the Gecko layout engine (used by Firefox) and of WebKit (which might seem to be Mac-centric due to its Apple roots). Both are designed to be cross-platform.

Trident (Microsoft's layout engine used by IE and, I assume, in the WebBrowser WinForms control) is closed-source.

But if you are just wanting to code a browser, then I consider writing a layout engine to be "reinventing the wheel", given the two engines that already exist.

Comment: I love to reinvent the wheel, it's a great learning experience. Actually I intend to construct my own wheel one day by machining the rim and hub and spokes on a metal lathe.

Comment: @samualjohnson I get your point.

Comment: @samualjohnson, very interesting comment. I like your determination and self confidence.